# How do I renew the Store certificate for Cordova in VS 2017

Tags: cordova, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2017

I read this link [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230260.aspx#Renew).

I have a Apache Cordova App and the Package.appxmanifest doesn't exists in the Visual Studio 2017. But, if I navigate (in Windows Explorer) to platforms/windows, I find it.

I try to copy this file to root/www to view in the VS 2017 ant try to open with App Manifest Designer but received an error not specified.

How I renew this crazy certificate?

I try to re-associate with the Store, create a new project and same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete guide to update the Windows 10/8.1 certificate. This is specifically targeted for apps created with Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio, I hope it helps anyone facing similar issues.

**[Renew Windows 10 PFX certificate for Cordova App with Visual Studio](https://www.andreszsogon.com/renew-windows-10-pfx-certificate-for-cordova-app-with-visual-studio/)**

Answer (score 3):

> How I renew this crazy certificate?

By default, Cordova template doesn't disclose the solution file for platform in Visual Studio. If you need to access it, you could open the folder explorer following the path below:

`Projects`> `Your Apps` > `platforms` > `Windows` > `Your Apps.sln`

After opening the solution for Windows platform, you could find the manifest and open it in Designer mode so that you're able to renew your certificate following that link:
[image]

Comment: Yes, but I'm using the new VS 2017 and it's a little bit diferent. This is a print: [link](https://imgur.com/RLO1ZO4)

Comment: It seems your screenshot looks like the Cordova project but not a single Universal Windows solution file like the above. Could you show me your current solution path in your screenshot?

Comment: Ok. This is the folder structure in Windows Explorer: [link](https://imgur.com/ZZDK95Z) and this is the file package.windows10.appxmanifest (in the folder platforms/windows - but I can't open) [link](https://imgur.com/a/L1OFe)

Comment: You don't need to open the manifest. You can open the `Cordova app.sln`  in your second screenshot through Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you so much! I open the `CordovaApp.sln` and do the instructions on MSDN. But other problem appears when I submit to the Windows Store: `Nome da família de pacotes inválido: 56768GilvanDev.CotaFcilVendedor_t0x7b5510rqre (esperado: 56768GilvanDev.CotaFcilVendedor_2bn5x35dm3bna)`

Comment: According to the error, you need to change the Package Family Name to the expected value `56768GilvanDev.CotaFcilVendedor_2bn5x35dm3bna` so that Dev Center can identify and accept it.